# MPAndroidChart refresh graph every X inputs

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

How to refresh graph dynamic?

- Init Chart.

  ```
      final LineData mLineData = mChart.getData();

      final ILineDataSet[] xSet = {mLineData.getDataSetByIndex(0)};

      final int xSetArrayItem = 0;

      if (xSet[xSetArrayItem] == null) {
          xSet[xSetArrayItem] = createSet("Ecg", getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
          mLineData.addDataSet(xSet[xSetArrayItem]);
      }
  ```
- After this I'm doing subscribe for real data and putting it into graph.

  ```
  mLineData.addEntry(new Entry(xValue++, ecgModel.getBody().getData()[i]), 0);

  mLineData.notifyDataChanged();

  // let the chart know it's data has changed
     mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
  // limit the number of visible entries
     mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(200);
  // move to the latest entry
    mChart.moveViewToX(xValue);
  ```
- And Problem is I don't want to scroll X Axis. I want to put for example 400 inputs clear graph and let chart draw new 400 inputs.

Something like this:

```
       if (xValue == 400) {
           xValue = 0;
           mLineData.clearValues();
           mChart.invalidate();
         }
```

**- But this clearing graph but then nothing is draw on chart.**

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
yVals.clear();
xLabel.clear();
set = new BarDataSet(yVals, "");
ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(set);
data = new BarData(dataSets);
ArrayList<Float> count = reportPojo.getCounts();
for (int i = 0; i < count.size(); i++) {
    float val = count.get(i);
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(i, val));
}
for (String label : reportPojo.getLabels()) {
    xLabel.add(label);
}
chart.setData(data);
set.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart.invalidate();
return set;
```

Comment: And where is dynamic refresh here? You are drawing chart after data is ready.

Comment: i too couldn't find a way so i used this instead notifying this chart is crashing mine also i was using in a recycler view.